# React Ajax 400 Bad Request on Rails-React

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I am trying to send some data over `\appointments` via POST request on my `handleFormSubmit` function. But for some reason I am always getting a `400 Bad Request Error`:

Here's my `Appointments.jsx` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import Appointment from './Appointment';
import AppointmentForm from './AppointmentForm';
import AppointmentsList from './AppointmentsList';

class Appointments extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
     super(props)

     this.state = {
       appointments: this.props.appointments,
       title: 'Put your event title',
       appointment_date: 'When would this happen?'
    };

    this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this)


   }

   handleUserInput(obj_value){
    this.setState(obj_value);
  }

  handleFormSubmit(){
    let apppointment = { 
      title: this.state.title, 
      appointment_date: this.state.appointment_date 
    };

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
            url: '/appointments',
            data: { apppointment }, 
            success: function(data){
              console.log(data); 
            }
          });
  }


   render(){
     return(
      <div>
        <AppointmentForm title={this.state.title} 
         appointment_date={this.state.appointment_date} 
         onUserInput={this.handleUserInput}
         onFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
         />
        <AppointmentsList appointments={this.props.appointments} />
     </div>
     )
   }
}

export default Appointments;
```

I am not sure yet but I think it has to do something with this code:

```
 $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
            url: '/appointments',
            data: { apppointment }, 
            success: function(data){
              console.log(data); 
            }
          });
```

Any idea what do i need to do in order to fix this?

Comment: 400 simply tells us that the parameters you are sending are not what the server is expecting. Can you check the network tab and confirm that the data is being send?

Comment: It says 400 xhr on the nettwork tab.

Comment: It saying 400 is pretty clear from the question, check the data being send and make sure that is the structure you need on the rails side

Comment: all I know is i am sending this: `let apppointment = { 
      title: this.state.title, 
      appointment_date: this.state.appointment_date 
    };` which is an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the network tab, you must select the post request and then go to the parameters you are sending and check if you are sending the data and if it is the right structure.
This is how it looks like on Chrome there is where you check the data you are sending
[image: This is how it looks on Chrome]
Try modifying your handleFormSubmit

```
handleFormSubmit() {
  let apppointment = JSON.stringify({
    title: this.state.title,
    appointment_date: this.state.appointment_date
  })
    $.ajax({
    url: '/appointments',
    type: "POST",
    data: apppointment,
    contentType: 'application/json'
  })
}
```

Comment: Nice. Smart guy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

meaby you can try with axios instance ajax